# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer iOS Simulator crash Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer crashes when running on simulator now.

Not possible to set the session.

```
var session: AVCaptureSession? {
    get{
        return (self.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).session
    }
    set(session) {
        (self.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).session = session
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running your application on an actual device instead of simulator. The `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` session cannot be captured on simulator.

Comment: It works on the actual device. But it is sometimes convenient to have it running on the simulator. It worked on the previous Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the crash here by checking like

```
 if let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) {
    // init AVCaptureSession here
 }
```